# AngularJS ng-src not launching image

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

My app.js file

```
angular.module('bandApp', ['ngRoute', 'RouteControllers']);

angular.module('bandApp').config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'templates/home.html',
        controller: 'HomeController'
    });
});
```

For controller:

```
var myCtrl = angular.module('RouteControllers', []);
.controller('jtronController', function($scope) {

    var jumbotronImage = {
        bandRef: "/images/band.jpg"
    };

    $scope.jumbotronImage = bandRef;
});
```

For HTML

```
<!Doctype html>
<html ng-app="bandApp">

    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Singing</title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">

        <script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.min.js"></script>
        <!--script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/a0-angular-storage/dist/angular-storage.min.js"></script>-->


    </head>

    <body>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#/">myBand</a>
                </div>
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li><a href="#/">Home</a></li>

                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
        <div ng-view>



            <!--adds a jumbotron-->
            <div ng-controller="jtronController">

                <!--adds a jumbotron
        <div class="container-full-bg" >-->

                <img ng-src="{{jumbotronImage.bandRef}}" />
            </div>
        </div>

        </div>
        <script src="js/app.js"></script>
        <script src="js/controller.js"></script>
    </body>

</html>
```

Below is the list of error (I renamed 'theBand' to 'bandRef' as shown in Controller.js code but not sure why is still popping up:

> ReferenceError: theBand is not defined
>       at new  (controller.js:11)
>       at Object.invoke (angular.js:4839)
>       at Q.instance (angular.js:10692)
>       at p (angular.js:9569)
>       at g (angular.js:8878)
>       at p (angular.js:9632)
>       at g (angular.js:8878)
>       at angular.js:8743
>       at angular.js:9134
>       at d (angular.js:8921)

Comment: Problem is `$scope.jumbotronImage = bandRef;` Use `$scope.jumbotronImage = jumbotronImage`

Comment: @Tushar, why is wrong? can pls explain.thanks

Comment: As you're using `jumbotronImage.bandRef` in `ng-src`, `jumbotronImage` should be an object and `bandRef` property on it should have the image path URL.

Comment: @Tushar sorry I tried that but not displaying the image still. I meant bandRef is representing the image source. thanks again for your quick response

Comment: @ Tushar. yes jumbotronImage is Object and bandRef is property. still no luck

Comment: Make sure the path in `bandRef` is correct. Also, check in console if you're getting any error, like 404

Comment: I got to work. my code is right it was to do with the server. The error occurs when connect to my localhost using  http://127.0.0.1 this connection but work after I use this one http://192.168...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do:

```
$scope.jumbotronImage = jumbotronImage.bandRef;
```

And then on the HTML:

```
<img ng-src="{{jumbotronImage}}" />
```

OR the other way would be:

```
$scope.jumbotronImage = jumbotronImage;
```

Then in the HTML:

```
<img ng-src="{{jumbotronImage.bandRef}}" />
```

Comment: Thank you but still not working after trying both ways

Comment: Got to have it working after I use  this connection http://192.168...instead of 127.0.0.1

Answer (score 3):

Correct the variable reference `$scope.jumbotronImage = bandRef` should be like below. It means you are assigning `jumbotronImage` reference to `jumbotronImage` scope variable to expose `jumbotronImage` value on view to make `{{jumbotronImage.bandRef}}` working.

```
var jumbotronImage = {
     bandRef: "/images/band.jpg"
};

$scope.jumbotronImage = jumbotronImage;
```

Answer (score 1):

you are given wrong reference $scope.jumbotronImage = bandRef; there is no variable like bandRef. refer this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects

```
 var myCtrl = angular.module('RouteControllers', []);
.controller('jtronController', function($scope) {

    var jumbotronImage = {
        bandRef: "/images/band.jpg"
    };

    $scope.jumbotronImage = jumbotronImage; // this is correct way
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$scope.jumbotronImage = function(){
 bandRef: "/images/band.jpg"
};
```

Try it once its working fine.

Comment: could you please elaborate it more.